# Executing EFcore Migrations inside a .NETStandard Library project

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

My question is basically: is it possible to use Entity Framework Core (and migrations) inside a .NET Standard 2.0 library project? (not a core project)

I currently have 2 projects:

- **ASP.NET Core** main project: I don't want anything with databases or EF inside this project, so I added a reference to the .NETstandard2.0 DAL project
- **.NETStandard2.0** data access layer project: EF Core with database migrations project for accessing the database. The main project uses this project to get data from the database.

For the .NETStandard DAL project, I use the following settings and classes: the `.csproj` file contains the dependencies for EF and migrations:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After calling `dotnet restore`, I created a `DbContext` descendant:

```
class MyTestContext: DbContext
{
    public MyTestContext(DbContextOptions<MyTestContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Class1> Class1Table { get; set; }
}
```

And added a `DbContextFactory` with `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` like:

```
class DbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyTestContext>
{
    public MyTestContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyTestContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=efmigrations2017;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
            optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(MyTestContext).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name));

        return new MyTestContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

Okay, so far everything works fine and the .NETStandard project builds successfully.

Now I want to create my first migration by executing:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

This throws an error:
[image]

If I understand the error message correctly, EF Core can only be used in .NET Core and .NET Framework projects and *NOT* in .NETStandard projects?

If that is true, how can I separate the EF database logic from my other applications?

If not, how can I get the migrations to work?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options.

One: Use your ASP.NET Core project as the startup project.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --startup-project ..\MyWebApplication
```

Two: Cross-target .NET Core in your class library. (Edit the `*.csproj`)

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Note: This property name becomes plural. -->
  <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The first option did the trick. but I still don't understand why there is need for an entrypoint to execute `dotnet ef`commands. I always thought it looks for a `DbContext` instance in the project. Many Thanks!

Comment: The entry point isn't needed; it's the DLLs. When NuGet restores for .NET Standard, all you get are reference assemblies that don't have any real implementation. BUT when NuGet restores the packages for your ASP.NET app, it gives you the .NET Core DLLs which can be executed. .NET Standard is just a spec, not a runtime.

Comment: @bricelam Have you considered adding above explanation to the EF tooling docs - this is a very essential (and hard to grasp) point

Comment: Mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/#frameworks

Comment: When using the PowerShell tools, the command is for example `Add-Migration MyName -Project NameOfTheStandardLibProject`

Comment: According to my experience ordering is important. `netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0` will be fine, but `netstandard2.0;netcoreapp2.0` will end up at the same error message.

Comment: When I try the second option I get this error:
"Unable to create an object of type 'MyDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728"

Do I have to change anything else? @bricelam